# Maximum static electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics

My question is if anyone knows the maximum experimental achievable value of static electric fields (like in a capacitor) and typical scales involved (like the distance separating the plates).

Here (http://www.ph.surrey.ac.uk/partphys/chapter4/ElectroAcc.html) I've found a value of $~40 MeV$ of final energy, but no mention to the distances involved (so that I could convert potential difference into electric field).

Any other reference would also be appreciated.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but pertinent: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209018/26969

Answer (score 1):

Maximum electric fields between metal plates in vacuum are on the order of $10^9 V/m$ due to the onset of (cold) electron field emission from the metal leading to exponentially increasing electron emission currents due to Fowler-Nordheim tunneling. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission

In dielectrics, the electric fields are usually much lower due to breakdown mechanisms.

Comment: worth expanding on the role of surface finish and temperature...